# XQuery Error: E For input string: "5770000"

Tags: xml, xquery

I want to grab some data from xml by xquery.
The original xml is something like:

```
<mondial>
<country id="AAA" name="BBB">
<name>BBB</name>
<city id="CCC" country="AAA">
<name>DDD</name>
<population>XXXX</population>
<located_at type="XX"/>
</city>
...
</country>
...
</mondial>
```

I write a XQuery like that:

```
let $cs:=//city[population >5000000 and located_at/@type='sea']
let $countries := //country
for $country in $countries
for $city in $cs
where $country/@id =$city/@country
return <seacity>{data($city/name)},{data($country/name)}</seacity>
```

I use Oxygen to do the conversion. An error come out:

> E For input string: "5770000"

I don't know where was wrong.
[image]

Comment: I don't recognize that error specifically, but you're missing an XQuery declaration, and your query references `locate_at` instead of `located_at`, the element name from your XML.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, it seems your XML is broken. Either you have a very strange font or the quotes are not the normal, specified ones (`'` and `"`), but some typographic quotes. Also, the red dot in front of the name makes me suspicious. Has this XML file been passed through some word editor?

Comment: @wst I change to located_at and it still not work...

Comment: @Jens Erat I think the XML file won't be wrong. It is provided by my professor and it work well for him... I sent a e-mail to him, but he haven't replied...

Comment: What happens if you run the query `/`? If this also fails, you can definitely blame the XML file. Is `5770000` by chance the very first attribute value in the file?

Comment: @JensErat If I quote 5000000 (change to "5000000"), no error show up. But still nothing in output except <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also in the same class. You need to put the population inside a number(). You also need to tell it to use the first population since some cities in the XML have multiple populations.

So instead of

`population > 5000000`

you would have

`number(population[1]) > 5000000`